# How to apply the source() function in R when the files to run are in different folders?

Tags: r, file, directory, connection

I have two R scripts (Script1.R and Script2.R) that are used by different people for the analysis of data. These scripts are, however, quite complicated and not very user friendly. Therefore, I want to create another script that can be used to run the two other scripts and to determine specific Values and directories.
To do so, I wanted to use the `source()` function.

My current code looks more or less like this:

```
#Data
individual_direction <-"C:/user/User1/Desktop/Data"

#Script 1
direction_script1 <- "SERVERNAME/userX/Team/R/XXX"

#Script 2
direction_script2 <- "SERVERNAME/userX/Team/R/YYY"

#Running the script using the directory mentioned above
source("SERVERNAME/userX/Team/R/XXX/Script1.R")

#Merging the newly created files according to their column or row
source("SERVERNAME/userX/Team/R/YYY/Script2.R")
```

When I then run this script, the following error message appears:

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
 cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
 cannot open file 'direction_script1/Script1.R': No 
such file or directory
```

However, when I enter the entire directory (e.g., `source("SERVERNAME/userX/Team/R/XXX/Script1.R")`), the script is run without any problem.

Can you please help me solve this problem?
Thank you very much for your help already in advance!

Comment: Rather than taking the approach you request I think that in the long run you'd be better off funding a more ribust solution: writing a package or using some sort of central code repository for example.  Sourcing files stored in user directories with uninformative, hard-coded, file names just has all my warning flags waving violently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `direction_script1` but then you don't use it in your example. If you just ran

```
source("direction_script1/Script1.R")
```

Then that doesn't expand the variable name. That's just a literal string. That's not the same as

```
source("SERVERNAME/userX/Team/R/XXX/Script1.R")
```

In order to combine the path with a variable, you can use the `file.path` function to build the correct path.

```
source(file.path(direction_script1, "Script.R"))
```